# Dissecting chatting apps like Tinder/FBMessenger in regards to sending encrypted messages

Tags: ios, security, ssl, network-programming

When I use Fiddle or Charles and see how text messages are sent/received from these apps, i can't easily see them. After some research, it seems that these texts are sent using TLS/SSL encryption. Q1. Is my understanding correct? Are all the texts sent/received encrypted by TLS (i'm not mentioning SSL because it seems that it's an outdated technology). Q2. Does encrypting all texts using TLS hit performance since server side and client side needs to go thru an extra step?

Comment: You better hope all of the messages are encrypted. Do you want to use an app where messages are sent in plain text?

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks. Then is it safe to assume that this encryption/decryption process on both server&client side hit performance negligibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Yes, https which used SSL/TLS encrypts the entire message and any query string.

Q2: Yes, there is a performance hit. It is generally negligible. All security adds a penalty in some fashion so the question is: "Do you want security?"